# Python - Change requests params so it doesn't start by "?=" and "&"

Tags: python-requests

So I have been trying to figure out how to work out things with requests.

So right now I have done something like:

```
url = 'www.helloworld.com'

params = {
    "": page_num,
    "orderBy": 'Published'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36'
                   ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.75 Safari/537.36')
}

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, timeout=12)
resp.raise_for_status()

print(resp.url)
```

and basically how it prints out now is:

`www.helloworld.com/?=2&orderBy=Published`

and what I wish to have is:

`www.helloworld.com/2?orderBy=Published`

How would I be able to change the params requests so it will end up like above?

Comment: Remove `page_num` from your `params` and manually concatenate it to `url`?

Comment: @ace Well as you can see page_num will be changing all the time, What I did for solution was `url = category_url + '{}'.format(page_num)` but Im not sure if that is the most effective one.

Comment: Looks about all right, I might just have something like `resp = requests.get(url + "/" + str(page_num), headers=headers, ...)`. I don't think there will be any difference in terms of "effectiveness".

Comment: @ace that actually true! Well! Thanks alot! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are trying to modify the target URL path, not the parameters. So you can't use the `params` parameters from requests to do that.

I suggest 2 options to do what you want:

- construct the url by hand. You can do it with string concatenations for simple cases, but there are modules to do it properly: https://pypi.org/project/furl/ , https://hyperlink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ , that are easier to use and more powerful than `urllib.parse.urljoin`
- use `apirequests` which is a simple wrapper around requests: https://pypi.org/project/apirequests

Sample using apirequests:

```
import apirequests

client = apirequests.Client('www.helloworld.com')
resp = client.get('/2', headers=headers, params=params, timeout=12)
# note that apirequests calls "resp.raise_for_status() automatically
```